# Show tooltip in ECharts given all input values null

Tags: javascript, echarts

I got an issue with showing hover tooltips with ECharts line graph when all input values of the graph are `null`.

The use case is a graph that might have some null/undefined values at certain points in time. For normal values, the graph would show the tooltip as usual. Whenever the value of the graph is `null` or `undefined`, I want the graph still show the hover tooltip but with custom format, for instance, 'N/A'.

The example code snippet is a simple EChart configuration that I took from EChart line graph examples and change the input data to `null`.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("main");
const chart = echarts.init(container);

const options = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: "axis",
    axisPointer: {
      type: "shadow",
      label: {
        show: true,
        overflow: "break"
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: "value",
    },
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: "line",
      data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    }
  ]
};

chart.setOption(options, true);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, ECharts does not show any tooltip when all input values are `null` (or `undefined`). It will show only when at least one of the input is not `null` nor `undefined`.

How can I force ECharts to show the tooltip regardless so that I can show the custom format hover?

MWE with all null values: https://codepen.io/htr3n/pen/bGRvyJJ

MWE with at least one non-null value: https://codepen.io/htr3n/pen/JjJLQYr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in ECharts 5.2 and previous versions. I opened a ticket with the ECharts team and they will fix and release the fix in v5.3.0.

Relevant bug ticket:

- https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/15821